# I want to report a user

Tags: discussion

I want to report a user because he has been the reason why I was banned from the site. I want strict actions to be taken against him and he should suffer to the same extent as me . Please make it sure. I feel *insecured* because this user always blocks and downvotes my answers.
Please ensure that he is not able to answer or comment on any of my questions. He should be blocked. Please ensure. He has threatened me also on this site.

Comment: Your profile shows one answer only...

Comment: I've made an attempt to salvage a general question out of this, but I'm not wholly convinced the resulting question makes sense to keep here. I just wanted to let readers know that the fact that I've edited it shouldn't be interpreted as an endorsement of this question.

Comment: @DavidZ maybe an answer by a mod could be to indicate the proper course of action (if there is one) if someone wishes to report a user.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I agree. I just wanted to wait a little while myself, before answering, to see what kind of response this gets from the community. For example if it had been downvoted to oblivion then perhaps that'd be a sign it wouldn't be worth answering.

Comment: I had to delete all my answers because of this guy. Thats why it show up one

Comment: What kind of threats were made? Actual "I'm going to do violence to you" statements? Or something far more mundane (e.g., "you might get banned if you keep doing X")?

Comment: OP appears to have an existing suspension for similar reasons (to cool down) on Math SE right now.

Comment: @DavidZ This post appears to have been 'downvoted to oblivion', and I don't think it's nice to have the name of a user sitting around in a question like this. Perhaps you could copy your answer to a new thread and make that community-wiki, so that we can point users there in the future (thouhgh I'm sure something similar exists on [meta.se])? We could even mark your answer as accepted there, which OP has not done here. That would reinforce the message somewhat. I frankly believe this focus on a particular user is harmful enough to justify deletion.

Comment: @DavidZ in partial support of Chair’s point, maybe one could just reset the username to something generic, though I wonder if this would affect authorship of comments.  Recognizing we only have one side of the story, the side presented by the OP is quite sad.

Comment: @Chair are you talking about the fact that a specific user's name is visible in the revision history? I believe the standard way of dealing with such things has been to edit it out, as I already did here, but I don't think it's normal to take any more extreme measures to obscure the username from view.

Comment: @DavidZ Yeah, I was talking about the user whose name has been removed in the edits. If it's not common to do that, then I guess we can leave it, but I do think it would be nice to delete this and make a proper canonical copy. There are some pretty serious accusations and it's not unlikely that people will look specifically at the post history.

Comment: @Chair If it comes to that we can redact the revision history, unless there's some reason that the whole question actually needs to be deleted and recreated and redaction wouldn't be good enough?

Comment: @DavidZ Oh, if you can delete the original version, that's great. That was actually my first thought, but I thought that would involve the SE team, so the easier option would simply be to create a new thread. If you can delete v1 here, that's perfect. (the gain from being able to accept the answer, which is only possible if there's  a separate thread, would be marginal)

Answer (score 7):

> I want to report a user because he has been the reason why I was banned from the site.

No, we do not issue suspensions because of other users. The real reason you were suspended was explained in the message that was sent to you when your suspension began.

> I want strict actions to be taken against him and he should suffer to the same extent as me . Please make it sure. I feel insecured because this user always blocks and downvotes my answers. Please ensure that he is not able to answer or comment on any of my questions. He should be blocked. Please ensure.

Any moderation actions that may be taken are not up to you to decide. It's inappropriate to make a public post asking for any of this.

If another member's behavior on the site concerns you, then you can report it to the moderators, but *not* by making a public post. The way to do so is by *flagging* the post(s) where it occurred. In the rare case where the behavior is something written in a profile or otherwise not flaggable directly, then you can flag any of the user's posts for moderator attention, and in the message, tell us what you want to report.

Generally, flag messages should simply describe what you observed. As the flagger, it's not your place to tell the moderators what to do about it - at least, not when the flag concerns problematic behavior from another user. If you're concerned that the action we take isn't appropriate, you should probably [get in touch with the Stack Exchange team](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact).

> He has threatened me also on this site.

That *is* something to be concerned about. You should report it by flagging any posts which contain threats.