# A user is harassing me in main

Tags: discussion, support

A user is consistently harassing me. I have warned them and they continued

Comment: I am in major need of help from a mod

Comment: consider flagging a mod using one example.

Comment: I have and they closed it

Comment: Not much to be done then, beyond constant flagging.  If you need mod help flags are the way to go.

Comment: i can't because they downvoted me to 11 taking away flaging

Comment: If it's any comfort all my questions were downvoted within one minute yesterday...  this kind of thing does happen, unfortunately.

Comment: Luna, in the future please refrain from calling out specific users in public. The behavior of the other user was *not* harassing, but your reactions were inappropriate. You'll get the hang of how we interact if you continue to hang out with us.

Comment: he actually was he said I knew nothing about dimentions and said i could just read wikipedia

Comment: for the record it is since I am on the autistic spectrum

Comment: Even though this is a different situation, I think the core of it is the same thing as [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10979/i-want-to-report-a-user) (and perhaps others), so I would mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Flag his post or comment, mods will handle it. They will likely don't say, what they did. If the harassment don't stop, you can go here to the meta. But in the rare cases as it happened to me, it always stopped.

Comment: I reported all of their comments and it took too long

Comment: Regarding "it took too long": the average flag-handling time by the diamond moderators over the past month is a couple of hours, which is about what it took to find and process the flags that you cast yesterday.

Comment: @Luna Regarding your 'about me', _"...takes downvotes as rude"_, it's very strongly encouraged that on SE, downvotes should not be taken personally. They are not meant as attacks and should not be perceived as rude. People downvote _a lot_ (self included), and it's the mechanism for keeping the quality of content high. When you're downvoted, don't think that it's someone disliking you. First, consider if your post has something dis-likable to it. If you can't see any problems, then shrug it off because there are so many votes being cast and some of them could be misfires.

Comment: @Chair I never got to finishing that. thanks for reminding me to finnish that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's very little to add to this moderator comment:

> if somebody's rude to you in the comments, there's no internet law that says you have to win the argument. If you see something particularly unpleasant, flag for moderator attention; then *disengage*. It'll be okay, I promise.

If you feel that you're being harassed, or that some other user is being rude or abusive (or just unwelcoming in some way), this meta isn't a good venue for it. Just **flag the comment and disengage.**

It's important to note that, while [flagging is a privilege obtained at 15 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) (and lost if you go below that for whatever reason), [**this is not the case for comment threads where you're participating**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311459/allow-new-users-to-flag-comments-on-their-own-posts): if you can comment on a post, then you can also flag comments on that post.

---

It's probably important to say this explicitly: several of your comments are on pretty gray areas, and they indicate that your side of the interactions has not been blameless either (and that's only with the comments which are currently visible right now). The fact that (you perceive that) others are being rude or abusive does *not* mean that you can reply with similar stuff. It can indeed be hard to turn away, but it's crucial to do so: flag the comments and walk away. A moderator will be there shortly to resolve the situation, and it won't help if they also have to deal with a lot of stuff from your side of the comments as well.

Comment: I can only comment on my questions

Comment: everyone can comment on their own

Comment: I voted to close the question as a duplicate so that future readers will be pointed to a relevant related resource, but I do think this is a very useful answer.

Comment: i think because of it being a good question it should have a higher vote than it has